# i have a problem in built my proxy set angular site

Tags: angular

I have a proxy config file in my angular site it runs well but when i build this it have a problem.

This is my proxyconfig.json

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://10.10.10.145:3005",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

And the response is:

> Request URL:http://localhost/api/user/login
>   Request method:POST
>   Remote address:127.0.0.1:80
>   Status code:
>   404
>   Version:HTTP/1.1
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

but have no response and give error message

Comment: Your proxy can only return data from a valid endpoint on the actual backend Since you got a `404` for a request to `api/user/login`, your first action should be to to verify that something is listening on that endpoint.

Comment: Does anything listen on port 3005?